# JQuery.when() not working for AJAX request on form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm attempting to use .when() and .done() to enter the form data into my db and then submit the form. However, on submit, the AJAX request is completely ignored and the form submits without entering the date into the database.

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Form Example</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h1>Processing an AJAX Form</h1>
      <form action="test.php" method="POST">
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Full Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email@example.com"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="superheroAlias">Superhero Alias</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="superheroAlias"
            name="superheroAlias"
            placeholder="Ant Man, Wonder Woman, Black Panther, Superman, Black Widow"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test_form").on('submit', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                superheroAlias: $("#superheroAlias").val(),
            };

            function testAjax () {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test2.php",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    encode: true,
                });
            }

            $.when( testAjax()
            ).done(function(response) {
                console.log('response: ', response)
                    $("#test_form").unbind('submit').submit();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm completely bewildered here. Console log does nothing so it seems like this entire script isn't running at all and the form submits as if the script isn't there. I also tested "test2.php" separately and it works perfectly so that script isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your test2.php is working?

If the test2.php file returns response successfully, then you should be able to console log inside of the done function.

```
$.when(testAjax())
.done(function(response) {
   console.log('response: ', response) here
   $("#test_form").unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

Comment: I tested "test2.php" separately and it works perfectly by itself. Console log outputs nothing so it seems like this entire script isn't running at all. I edited my question to include the full code for context.

Comment: are you sure you enter #test_form submit?